# Can you change the revisions limit in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

Is it possible to change the limit of 100 revisions in Google Drive?

I've been using Dropbox for several years, and just recently moved to Google Drive. I really like the revision system of Dropbox, which keeps unlimited revisions for each file (even if it's not really unlimited, I've never hit the limit). At least when it comes to Pro accounts.
Does google provide the same functionality on their paid services (and I'm talking mainly on the 2$ accounts that comes with 100GB of space).

While 100 should be more than enough for private use, there are times when I'm working on documents and hit Ctrl+S every minute or so.. so each time I do that, a new revision is created, and I hit the 100 limit quite fast.

Comment: How do you know that 100 is the limit?

Comment: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2409045?hl=en - See `Automatically deleting files`.
There is also a limit of 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

As it may seem, google has got this limit probably hard-wired. After some revisions, GDrive starts to make pruning (merges).
You may see this explained here:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843?rd=1
After the title

```
Unable to see a previous version of your file?
```

Comment: Is it the same on their paid services? (There are paid plans of $2 and $10 which provide 100GB and 1TB respectively)

Comment: Other than having more space, paid plans don't appear to come with additional functionality. At least I haven't found anything on their website.

Comment: About that i do not know, you better contact the google drive support to get the exact answer to your question.
But from what i could find, the revision limit is the same.